# cURL is retrieving encoded HTML from Pirate Bay

Tags: php, curl

I'm creating a script that is scraping the site **www.piratebay.se**. The script was working OK two-three days ago but now I'm having problems with it.

This is my code:

```
$URL = 'http://thepiratebay.se';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "language=pt_BR; c[thepiratebay.se][/][language]=pt_BR");

$fonte = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
echo $fonte;
```

The response of this code is not clean HTML, but looks like this instead:

��[*s۸N>��k�9��-ىmI7��$�8�.v��͕���$h���y�G�Sg:ӷ>�5*���`�ʱ�aor&`���.v)���������) d�w��8w�l����c�u""1����F*G��ِ�2$�6�C�}��z(bw�� 4Ƒz6�S��t4�K��x�6u���~�T���ACJb��T^3�USPI:Mf��n�'��4��� ��XE�QQ&�c5�`'β�T Y]D�Q�nBfS�}a�%� ���R) �Zn��̙ ��8IB�a����L�

I already tried to use user agent on .htaccess, PHP and cURL but to no success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
```

Tested on my local environment, works fine with it.

Comment: Works like a char! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, i did this. We have to wait some time to be able to do it.